# multipurpose index command with xparse: conditionals as arguents of \index not working

Tags: conditionals, indexing, xparse

I want to define a multipurpose index command, \xindex{text}[index]/parent/  with one mandatory and two optional arguments. It should (i) print 'text' in the main text, (ii) send 'index' (or 'text') to the index if 'index' is specified (or not), and (iii) if 'parent' is specified, it should format (ii) as subentry of a main entry in the index. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\NewDocumentCommand{\xindex}{mod//}
% #1: text 
% #2: index (if given, it overrides #1)
% #3: parent  (if given, #1,#2 become subentries)
{\IfValueTF{#3}%
{% if parent is specified, create parent entry
#1\index{#3@\textbf{#3}!%
% create subentry:
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{#2}@\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\emph{#1}}{#2}}%
{% if #3 'parent' is absent, create regular entry:
#1\index{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{#2}@\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\emph{#1}}{#2}}%
}%
}%
}%

\begin{document} 

\xindex{test1},
\xindex{test2}[Test2],
\xindex{test3}/tests/,
\xindex{test4}[Test4]/tests/

\printindex    
\end{document}
```

After compiling latex and running makeindex, I was hoping to get the following output for the maint text,

```
test1, test2, test3, test4
```

and for the index (the rightmost 1 is the page number):

```
test1, 1  
Test2, 1  
tests  
   test3, 1  
   Test4, 1
```

Instead, my code produces for the main text:

```
, , test3test3 test4test4
```

and for the index:

```
Test3, 1  
Test4, 1
tests  
   test3, 1  
   Test4, 1
```

I suspect that I have misunderstood how the conditional command \IfNoValueTF operates, or how \index interprets it. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced `}`.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\xindex}{mod//}{%
  % #1: text
  % #2: index (if given, it overrides #1)
  % #3: parent  (if given, #1,#2 become subentries)
  \IfValueTF{#3}%
    {% if parent is specified, create parent entry
     #1\index{#3@\textbf{#3}!%
       % create subentry:
       \IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{#2}@\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\emph{#1}}{#2}%
      }%
    }
    {% if #3 'parent' is absent, create regular entry:
     #1\index{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{#2}@\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\emph{#1}}{#2}}%
    }%
}
```